# Terminator not opening and giving following error

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, terminator

Recently,  I have installed `zsh` shell. After that I tried to open terminator software then it was crashing and giving following error:

Also, after installation of `zsh`, I have set the default login shell as `/bin/bash` only.

```
$ terminator
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
```

Comment: Not sure, but to me this looks like a bug in Terminator... You should consider filing a bug report on Launchpad against it.

Comment: These are just warnings. I have exactly the same ones and `terminator` works perfectly (I too have `zsh` as my shell). 14.04, stock versions for both `zsh` abd `terminator`. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: What is your `terminator` configuration (it's located in `~/.config/terminator/config`)?